# TypeScript Recursive generic argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create converter class to convert a map of methods into a map of methods results. Each method has an argument (map of methods results).
But I can't type the argument. Is it possible?

*TypeScript playground: [here](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYAoA9AKm+q2UAwgPYB2AbhPLNVCQGb0BGAVhKvUwLYSwAWJACZgoiMrBIt2nRlF4Dho+BDAgANrDAA6fNkzpk6gIZhRAcT614YAEIhE6odQA8AWSgQAHrTIioAN5QANrizl4AXDAI4gDmALpRABQKgiJRxmQAngCUUAC8AHxQmVlQAL7FAfhQAA4gzOooUCpqmmBRQcEACmJkUADWEFlybolQAEp8IPBkACpZtRDuPfHF5QDcNcjkcPAgqCTwKXxpHVBuedVQN1ACiDqtGloFUADybByw2kNZYCeKEQ5bQqIQHCBJJLGZDIAA0g2GeSKgRqtygOzIcHkp2Er1SSmCv3iWzRNxUsBm-Q+Mm+zgY4gg3XgJCWNCyUJh8LIxl48OupJusT4ySRVVRApa01m2MBSXuj1UzzAORJEvK4pu5RV4vKfK1qvV6sMu1gUFizFeZAgAHcoJZYNY7A4nNQkvzaHAAIwigrFAAMsJqHtgACYfciyBp1IGbsGAMzJJ7tKA4O6LCBCEqiUoETCiyVtLTaYOe9D69DGzGm1reqCR7jMOj5M3MEGK9rF1SwT0p7D1xvwfQbFOYNNLTM7eAqVDqLKVrGtMN1qOvc1tws6YMh3uR9TqIcjscZ9FHaewWfz6uqOMAQSi-abLfXSs7cDjO5ADeoB8wo9g6czcRJzPWcsxKbI+jgCBjEzOQH3gS8CzjWwoj2OJV1bJMi3jD8v0HTBh1-KAAFEpyOMRRDIEhTWQYxYGQfgM10IA)*

```js
"use strict"
/**
 * Converter of object of methods into object of methods results.
 */
class GettersBuilder<M extends { [index: string]: (methods: any) => any }> {
  public results: { [P in keyof M]: ReturnType<M[P]> };
  constructor(methods: M) {
    this.results = Object.keys(methods).reduce((acc, key) => {
      const method = methods[key];
      return Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {
        get: () => {
          return method(this.results);
        }
      });
    }, {});
  }
}

const gb = new GettersBuilder({
  test1: () => 0,
  test2: () => null,
  test3: (results /* typed as any */) => results.test1
});

const res1: number = gb.results.test1 /*number*/; // typed correctly
const res2: null = gb.results.test2 /*null*/; // typed correctly
const res3A: number = gb.results.test3 /*number*/; // typed incorrectly as any instead of number
const res3B: string = gb.results.test3 /*number*/; // Error is not catched.
```

Right now typing is not working because of a type `(methods: any) => any`. But when I change the type to `(methods: { [P in keyof M]: ReturnType<M[P]> }) => any`
then type for GettersBuilder.results is converted to any.

*TypeScript playground [here](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYAoA9AKm+q2UAwgPYB2AbhPLNVCQGb0BGAVhKvUwLYSwAWJACZgoiMrBIt2nRlF4Dho+BDAgANrDAA6fNkzpk6gIZhRAcT614YAEIhE6odQA8AWSgQAHrTIioAN5QANrizl4AXDAI4gDmALpRABQKgiJRQcEACmJkUADWEACecm6JUABKfCDwZAAqRQAOEO7Z8QB8UAC+AJRQALydxmRF3Z0B+FCNIMzqKFAqappgGSE54gXFpeVVsDX1TS1ubZ1dANyTyORw8CCoJPApfGkrUG59E1BfUAKIOosaLQDKAAeTYHFg2kKRTAT0UIh62hUQjuECSSWMyGQABpNkU+oNApNvlArmQ4PJnsJgaklMFofELiSvio9rVQeDUNpnAxxBAsvASM0aEUMVjcdDcZ9mV9YnxkgTxsSZQtquzaUIkr9-qpAWAekyVV1lV9eobTVKzZNjcbDNdYFBYsxgWQIAB3KCWWDWOwOJzUJLS2hwACMCoGnQADNjJsHYAAmcOEsgadQxr5xgDMyQByygOB+hyEUFMJZGBEwitVSy02jjIfQVrt5IdizDUBT3GYdH6juYSN1yzrqlgIfz2E73fg+jO+cwheaxfEV3gKlQ6lGpeGo3EcAgxmLckn1GbFMWiY7qeBToHNZ0cfj45T6nUM7nC4gS7IK7XsA3JdEbdcj3A8uEvF9T1bVRMwAQSiY94Gvftc1rLMnxALtqDfTB51gItch-CF-y3ctd1oUCjwwqdIOrTNbCiG44iQ289WHOBM3QzDp0wWccKgABRVcHjEUQyBIB1kGMWBkH4T9tCAA)*

```js
"use strict"
/**
 * Converter of object of methods into object of methods results.
 */
class GettersBuilder<M extends { [index: string]: (methods: { [P in keyof M]: ReturnType<M[P]> }) => any }> {
  public results: { [P in keyof M]: ReturnType<M[P]> };
  constructor(methods: M) {
    this.results = Object.keys(methods).reduce((acc, key) => {
      const method = methods[key];
      return Object.defineProperty(acc, key, {
        get: () => {
          return method(this.results);
        }
      });
    }, {});
  }
}

const gb = new GettersBuilder({
  test1: () => 0,
  test2: () => null,
  test3: (results /* typed as any */) => results.test1
});

const res1: number = gb.results.test1 /*number*/; // typed incorrectly as any instead of number
const res2: null = gb.results.test2 /*null*/; // typed incorrectly as any instead of null
const res3A: number = gb.results.test3 /*number*/; // typed incorrectly as any instead of number
const res3B: string = gb.results.test3 /*number*/; // Error is not catched.
```

Comment: Would you be open to using `this` instead of an extra argument ? We can easily type `this`  as begin the same type as the object literal: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20x%3CM%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3E(m%3A%20M%20%26%20ThisType%3CM%3E)%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20M%5D%3A%20ReturnType%3CM%5BP%5D%3E%20%7D%20%7B%20return%20null%3B%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20k%20%3D%20x(%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%20return%20this.a()%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I like it. But can't apply because I need to repeat original signature `(results: { [P in keyof M]: ReturnType<M[P]> }) => any`
I have researched the issue and found out that many devs can't solve the problem.